# VBA - Add PivotField Filter to Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that creates a Pivot Table and adds the desired "PivotFields" to the table.. The one thing I cannot seem to figure out is how to add a "Pivot Field" under the "Filters" area.

Here is the code I have:

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()
    'PURPOSE: Creates a brand new Pivot table on a new worksheet from data in the ActiveSheet
    'Source: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

    Dim pvtSht As Worksheet
    Dim summarySht As Worksheet
    Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim StartPvt As String
    Dim SrcData As String
    Dim pf As PivotField

    'Determine the data range you want to pivot
    SrcData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

    'Create a new worksheet
    Set pvtSht = Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"

    'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
    StartPvt = pvtSht.Name & "!" & pvtSht.Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

    'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
    Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

    'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
    Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
    TableName:="P1")

    'Insert Row Fields
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(" DNS Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(" Operating System")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("P1")
        .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "P1").PivotFields("IP Address"), "Count of IP Addresses"
        .PivotFields("IP Address").Orientation = xlRowField
    End With

    With Sheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("P1").PivotFields("IP Address")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With

    Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name")

    'Collapse Pivot Field
    pf.ShowDetail = True

    'Expand Pivot Field
    pf.ShowDetail = False

    'Create a new worksheet
    Set summarySht = Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary"

End Sub
```

This is what it outputs on the Pivot Table sheet:

[image]

This is what I need it to output (Notice *Risk Rating* under **Filters**):

[image]

This is what needs to be displayed on the sheet:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields("Risk Rating")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I put the with block just after my last with block and I get the error - Unable to get PivotFields property of the PivotTable class.

Comment: @pnuts actually the error was that I needed a space just before the R in " Risk".. So it is working perfectly now :)

Comment: @Maddy, Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Not related to your error you are raising here, but just a notice to shorten your code a lot (and make it clearer to read):

You already `Set` your `PivotTable` so nicely here:

```
Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
    TableName:="P1")
```

So why not use it, and make the rest of your `PivotTable` settings like this:

```
With pvt
    With .PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With .PivotFields(" DNS Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With

    With .PivotFields(" Operating System")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
    End With

    .AddDataField .PivotFields("IP Address"), "Count of IP Addresses"
    .PivotFields("IP Address").Orientation = xlRowField

    With .PivotFields("IP Address")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With

    Set pf = .PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name")
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for this, as you've seen on my past posts I have quite a bit of unnecessarily long code which I am working on making shorter. So thank you :)